# Main thread's execution context

Tags: iphone

I need ideas on the following -

In the main thread at some point of execution say Point A(sequential logic), I need to remember the state of execution and delegate the execution of some other logic onto another thread, and let the main thread handle the UI events etc. When the delegated logic completes on the other thread then the flow of execution should continue from the point A and should recollect the entire execution context and proceed as if it never paused there.

Regards,
Sunil Phani Manne

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to implement this exactly the way you're saying (for example `do(things)... yield(other_thread); ...do(more_things);`.

Here are a couple other options I can think of (you'd have to implement these yourself, using delegates or notifications for example; I'm just giving a basic outline of how it would work):

```
do(things)
[object doStuffOnOtherThreadWithCallback:^{ // block-based
    do(more_things)...
}];
```

or...

```
  do(things)
  [object doStuffOnOtherThreadWithCallbackTarget:self // target/selector-based
                                        selector:@selector(callbackSelector)];
}
- (void)callbackSelector {
    do(more_things)...
}
```

Comment: Even here the state/context is the problem... :(

Comment: If you use my first solution (with the block, `^{}`), the state (local variables and such) will be accessible inside the block.

Comment: Yeah have to think deeply about this in arriving at a solution. But then, I have to drop the support for 3.x devices..

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is encapsulating the whole sequential logic that comes after Point A in your delegate and then execute it on the main thread when the secondary thread ends.

In other words, when you start the thread by calling, e.g.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:sel toTarget:target withObject:delegate]
```

you can implement your target `target` so that it has a specific selector `completion` that is called at the end of `sel` on the main thread, like this (this is the your `delegate` class):

```
@implementation YOURDelegateClass {
   .....
   -(void)completion {

   }

   -(void)sel {
     ...
     ...
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(@"completion") withObject:self];
   }
}
```

Of course you have many sub-options available here, like using a different call to start the background execution, etc.

The important point is that: you have to encapsulate in a selector all the logic that comes after Point A, and that you have to schedule the execution of this selector on the main thread, in order to get back to your context (although your context will have changed in the meantime because you will also have updated the UI).

EDIT:

Having to schedule the execution on the main thread defeats blocks from being suitable for this kind of callback. On the other side, block have the advantage that they in some limited sense give you access to the same lexical context in which the block was defined (which is roughly what you call context).

A workaround for this could be the following. Before detaching the new thread, store in a delegate the block you would like to execute at completion:

```
typedef void(^CustomBlock)(void);
@property (nonatomic, copy) CustomBlock customBlock;
....
int a = ...
delegate.customBlock = ^{
   NSLog(@"hello %d.....", a);
}
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:sel...
....
-(void)completion {
    [self customBlock];
}
```

Of course, you only get the context preservation that is guaranteed to you by block. But here you hit against a limit of the language.

If you need more context preservation, then the only possibility is encapsulating that context in your delegate class ivars.

Comment: The problem here is the state and the context. I lose the context. It is a very difficult to remember the entire context and pass it on the second part. And just think of having so many such points like point A.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure. There, most probably, isn't any direct feature in Cocoa that does that. Since you're saying that you can't duplicate the resources onto the new thread (for a very good reason), I am going to suggest that you make use of [`NSUndoManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For every change you make in the thread, push an undo operation for that change onto the undo manager. At the end of the thread, execute all the undo operations in the undo manager object. This should, if done correctly, restore your state. Now, since the idea is untested, there could be a chance that not all actions can be undone. You will have to check that out first.

Comment: That's a nice idea but may be not applicable in my case though. Thanks!